# Thinks she’s supposed to pee inside

Tags: training

I take puppy (7mo) outside during the day.  I let her sniff around for 15 min or so. When she goes, I praise her and give her a treat. Other times, She goofs around and holds it until she gets inside. Immediately pees on the floor. When I take her out first thing in the morning, she will go without any problems.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Please add a clear question or aim you want to reach. As it is now, you tell what is the status, but give no hint in what direction you want to proceed...

Comment: Hardest lesson I learned during the brief time we had a dog is that you need to stay out until she goes, until she learns that this is the time to do so. If that means you're out for an hour while training her, you're out for an hour.